# ContextApi, useReducer, & Typescript - calculated value is not accessible on component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

Apologies for the somewhat opaque title, but I am having difficulties being more precise here.

So I have a Context/Reducer Logic, where I initialise the context with some values. I then have a reducer Logic on a custom Provider and use `useMemo` to calculate `values`. When trying to access one on of those values (that isn't in the state/initialState) on a component typescript gets angry at me and tells me that said value does not exist on State. What is the best way to remedy this warning?

I have the following definition of a Context/Reducer.

```js
interface State {
  displaySidebar: boolean
}

const initialState = {
  displaySidebar: false
}

type Action =
  | {
      type: 'OPEN_SIDEBAR'
    }
  | {
      type: 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR'
    }

const UIContext = React.createContext<State>(initialState)
UIContext.displayName = 'UIContext'

const uiReducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'OPEN_SIDEBAR': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displaySidebar: true,
      }
    }
    case 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displaySidebar: false,
      }
    }
  }
}

const UIProvider: FC = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(uiReducer, initialState)
  const openSidebar = (): void => dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_SIDEBAR' })
  const closeSidebar = (): void => dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR' })
  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...state,
      openSidebar,
      closeSidebar,
    }),
    [state]
  )
  return <UIContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

export const useUI = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(UIContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUI must be used within a UIProvider`)
  }
  return context
}

export const ManagedUIContext: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <UIProvider>
    <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  </UIProvider>
)
```

now when I try to use  `const {closeSidebar} = useUI()` in a component typescript gets angry with me and tells me that `Property 'closeSidebar' does not exist on type 'State'.` I get that, but I was not able to figure out how to properly add `closeSidebar` to the `React.Context` type.

Comment: where do you create context? you can provide the type you need when you create it, like `React.createContext<MyType>`

Comment: fair point. let me include this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create context you tell TS that its type will be `State`, so it doesn't expect anything else to be there. If you want to add additional fields you can create an intersection type, state + methods, either as a named type of just `React.createContext<State & {openSidebar : ()=> void, closeSidebar: ()=> void}>`. Note that as your initial state doesn't have methods you either need to make them optional or provide some sort of dummy versions.

Comment: whats the benefit of doing your way over just adding the variables to both `State` and `initialState`? I'd really like to only add it in one place, but that does not seem to be possible. Thx for the reply

Comment: You could, but the idea of state in react is that it is supposed to be just serializable data, while JavaScript methods are non-serializable logic. Redux-toolkit even includes a middleware that will shout at you if you try to add methods to the state. While you're not using it, it is still a good idea to follow the rules, it makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: much appreciated!